# Extracting vertex and triangle data from SharpDX toolkit model

Tags: c#, game-physics, sharpdx, physics-engine

I'm working on creating convex hulls and triangle meshes from models loaded in with SharpDX 2.6.

I've found some example code for extracting the vertices and indices from a model, but they're based around XNA and (what appears to be) DirectX 9 - my program is using SharpDX with DirectX 11 (and SharpDX toolkit, so a lot of things are similar to XNA).

The code I've found to extract vertices and indices (as triangles):

```
public void ExtractData(List<JVector> vertices, List<JOctree.TriangleVertexIndices> indices, Model model)
    {
        Matrix[] bones_ = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(bones_);
        foreach (ModelMesh mm in model.Meshes)
        {
            Matrix xform = bones_[mm.ParentBone.Index];
            foreach (ModelMeshPart mmp in mm.MeshParts)
            {
                int offset = vertices.Count;
                Vector3[] a = new Vector3[mmp.NumVertices];
                mm.VertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(mmp.StreamOffset + mmp.BaseVertex * mmp.VertexStride,
                    a, 0, mmp.NumVertices, mmp.VertexStride);
                for (int i = 0; i != a.Length; ++i)
                    Vector3.Transform(ref a[i], ref xform, out a[i]);

                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) vertices.Add(new JVector(a[i].X, a[i].Y, a[i].Z));

                if (mm.IndexBuffer.IndexElementSize != IndexElementSize.SixteenBits)
                    throw new Exception(
                        String.Format("Model uses 32-bit indices, which are not supported."));
                short[] s = new short[mmp.PrimitiveCount * 3];
                mm.IndexBuffer.GetData<short>(mmp.StartIndex * 2, s, 0, mmp.PrimitiveCount * 3);
                JOctree.TriangleVertexIndices[] tvi = new JOctree.TriangleVertexIndices[mmp.PrimitiveCount];
                for (int i = 0; i != tvi.Length; ++i)
                {
                    tvi[i].I0 = s[i * 3 + 2] + offset;
                    tvi[i].I1 = s[i * 3 + 1] + offset;
                    tvi[i].I2 = s[i * 3 + 0] + offset;
                }
                indices.AddRange(tvi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what I've been able to rework it into (for DirectX 11 with SharpDX toolkit ease):
I've generalised it into simply building an octree from a model, but the main chunk of the pipeline is still the same.

```
    public static Octree BuildOctree(Model model) {

        List<JVector> vertices = new List<JVector>();
        List<TriangleVertexIndices> indices = new List<TriangleVertexIndices>();           
        Matrix[] bones = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(bones);   

        foreach (ModelMesh modelMesh in model.Meshes)
        {               
            JMatrix boneTransform = PhysicsSystem.toJMatrix(bones[modelMesh.ParentBone.Index]);
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in modelMesh.MeshParts)
            {
                int offset = vertices.Count;              
                var meshVertices = meshPart.VertexBuffer.Resource.Buffer.GetData<JVector>();
                for (int i = 0; i < meshVertices.Length; ++i)
                {
                    JVector.Transform(ref meshVertices[i], ref boneTransform, out meshVertices[i]);
                }
                vertices.AddRange(meshVertices);    // append transformed vertices

                var indexElements = meshPart.IndexBuffer.Resource.GetData<short>(); // this is dangerous if the model uses larger integers

                // Each TriangleVertexIndices holds the indices that constitute a triangle primitive
                TriangleVertexIndices[] tvi = new TriangleVertexIndices[indexElements.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i <= tvi.Length - 2; i += 3) {
                    tvi[i].I0 = indexElements[i + 0] + offset;
                    tvi[i].I1 = indexElements[i + 1] + offset;
                    tvi[i].I2 = indexElements[i + 2] + offset;
                }
                indices.AddRange(tvi);  // append triangles           
            }
        }
        Octree ot = new Octree(vertices, indices);
        //ot.BuildOctree(); // (already happens in Octree constructor)
        return ot;
    }
```

I'm using a variant of this code (without the triangle calculations, just vertices) to create a convex hull shape in a similar manner.

My questions are:
Is there any way I could improve this code?

Is this code correct/are there things that you immediately see as potentially wrong?

When I use this method to extract vertices from a model of a box (same one used in the Jitter tutorials), I get a representation that's not quite a box with not quite evenly distributed shape mesh detail which then slows down the collisions much more than using the built in BoxShape primitive (60fps flat when using BoxShape, ~20-30 when using a single box colliding with a static TerrainShape). Why might this be the case?

I feel that, while my rewriting of the code produces some output, it doesn't feel optimal at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't extract data easily. The elements in the vertex buffer can vary depending on the model vertex structure (see the [compiler code](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/Toolkit/SharpDX.Toolkit.Compiler/Model/ModelCompiler.cs#L704), you can have `Vector4`, `Vector3`, `Vector2` or even 16 bits).

To correctly decode it, you need to access the layout at runtime and decode the vertex buffer with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer xoofx,

If you were presented with the task of constructing a list of vertices in order to construct Jitter Physics' ConvexHullShape(), how would you go about doing so?
(I ask this mainly for the insight from the person who actually developed SharpDX)

An example from Jitter using XNA is linked below:

https://code.google.com/p/jitterphysics/source/browse/trunk/JitterDemo/JitterDemo/PhysicsObjects/ConvexHullObject.cs

Do you agree with the way they do it and how would this be best converted to a SharpDX solution?

Thanks

Comment: Don't have time to write a complete solution, but this is basically the idea. The difference with the XNA version is that the XNA GetData is able to get part of the vertex stream, while with SharpDX you have to calculate the offset to the correct vertex element and iterate on the raw buffer to decode it. The code is a bit more laborious to write.

Comment: The offset part was confusing me when I wrote my solution (I'm new to 3D graphics, please excuse me).

So I want to be iterating over each mesh's vertex buffer in the model, applying applicable bone transforms (new to me) to each vertex and then appending that buffer's vertices to an ordered list of vertices - essentially squashing many meshes into one vertex list? Offset for?

That's all that's needed to create a convex hull, as one can be constructed from a point cloud without any vertex index information, but to create a representative mesh, i'd need the indices/TriangleVertexElements.

Comment: the data you get from the vertex buffer can contains other elements like Vector2 UV, Vector3 normals...etc. So each vertex is larger than just a position, but for each vertex, the first 3 floats are the position. So with the vertex stride which is the size in bytes of a vertex (for which I'm not sure you have it directly without recomputing the size from VertexElements), you need to iterate on the vertex buffer data, by VertexStride bytes, and taking the first Vector3 from it. With some unsafe code, should be straightforward.